# Как с помощью XPath достать часть текста?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, xml, xpath

Здравствуйте, есть исходная строка вида:

```
<a class="b-user__link" href="https://siteadress/users/username/"><b class="b-user__first-letter">o</b>blablabla</a>
```

Необходимо достать только значение username.

С помощью `//a/@href` удаётся достать `https://siteadress/users/username/`.

Однако только значение username из ссылки достать не удаётся.

Не знаю какой код применить к исходной строке, чтобы на выходе было значение `username`.

Возможно ли это сделать с помощью XPath? Если нет, то каким образом? Может быть регулярные выражения?

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, пример кода, где xpath `//a/@href` не работает.

Comment: `//a/@href` работает, однако я хочу достать не ссылку целиком, а часть текста, содержащегося внутри ссылки.

Comment: Ясно. Тогда что **конкретно** не получается? Приведите код, который даёт неправильный результат, объясните, какой результат ожидается.

Comment: *Однако часть href не удаётся.* - какую часть???

Comment: часть ссылки, а именно `username`. Внёс дополнения в исходный вопрос, надеюсь, что теперь смог донести свою проблему.

Comment: А username всегда в конце?

Comment: Да, всегда в конце ссылки, в виде `/username/`, однако количество символов в username и их тип (могут быть буквы, цифры, специальные знаки) не фиксировано.

Comment: С помощью XPath извлекаете значение узла XML. А далее парсите плоский текст. XPath тут бесполезен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно получить это значение с помощью регулярного выражения:

```
var username = s.match(/[^\/]+(?=\/?$)/)
```

См. [демо онлайн](https://regex101.com/r/rB4tY4/1). Тут `s` — это значение *href*, который вы получаете с помощью `//a/@href`.

**Подробности**

- `[^\/]+` - 1 или более символов, отличных от `/`
- `(?=\/?$)` - 1 или 0 знаков `/` в конце строки.

Другой вариант — использовать `.replace()`:

```
.replace(/.*\/([^\/]+)\/?$/, '$1')
```

См. [другое онлайн-демо](https://regex101.com/r/rB4tY4/2). Тут `.*\/` находит весь текст от начала до последнего слеша, включая слеш, потом `([^\/]+)\/?$` находит и захватывает `username` в группу №1 и её мы и оставляем в результате, используя `$1` в шаблоне замены.

JS-демо:

```js
function createElementFromHTML(htmlString) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = htmlString.trim();
  return div.firstChild; 
}
function getElementsByXpath(doc, xpath) {
  var result = [];
  var nodesSnapshot = document.evaluate(xpath, doc, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null );
  for ( var i=0 ; i < nodesSnapshot.snapshotLength; i++ ){
    result.push( nodesSnapshot.snapshotItem(i).value.replace(/.*\/([^\/]+)\/?$/, '$1') );
  }
  return result;
}

var s = '<a class="b-user__link" href="https://siteadress/users/username/"><b class="b-user__first-letter">o</b>blablabla</a><a class="b-user__link2" href="https://siteadress/users/username2/"><b class="b-user__first-letter2">o</b>blablabla</a>';
var dom = createElementFromHTML('<div>' + s + '</div>');

console.log( getElementsByXpath(dom, "//a/@href") );
```